# Fatia uma array

Tags: python, array, gráfico

Estou tendo problema nos valores do x2 ao tentar fatiar para exibir no gráfico 2 não aparece nada e não estou conseguindo ver onde estou errando?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xold = np.random.rand()
N = 3000

x1 = np.empty((N))
print("x1:", x1)

for k in range(N):
    x_new = 4*xold*(1 - xold)
    xold = x_new
    x1[k] = x_new

comp = len(x1)
x2 = x1 + 0.25*np.std(x1)*np.random.rand(1,comp)

plt.figure(1)
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(x1[:-1], x1[1:], 'bo')
plt.title('MAPA LOGISTICO 1')
plt.ylabel('x1k)')
plt.xlabel('x1(k-1)')

plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(x2[:-1], x2[1:], 'bo')
plt.title('MAPA LOGISTICO 2')
plt.ylabel('x(2k)')
plt.xlabel('x2(k-1)')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que da forma que você está calculando, `x2` vira uma matriz de duas dimensões, sendo que a dimensão mais externa só tem 1 elemento.

Dessa forma, `x2[1:]` e `x2[:-1]` não retornam nada, pois são fatias vazias.

Uma forma de resolver é extraindo o vetor interno, ou seja, antes de plotar, rode:

```
x2 = x2[0]
```

O resultado:

[image: plot]

Comment: Não compreendi bem o sua resposta

Comment: @RonaldoSouza ok, porém, da forma que escrevi, para mim, parece clara o suficiente, portanto, seria necessário que apontasse o que não entendeu, para que possamos editar e melhorá-la.

Comment: Já compreendi o que tu falaste, e resolveu. Valeu